# How to add more remoteMethod to Built-in Models (say User) in Loopback

Tags: node.js, express, loopbackjs, strongloop

How to add more remoteMethod to Built-in Models (say User) in Loopback?

I have created a common/models/user.js and added the following code

```
var loopback = require('loopback');
var User = loopback.User;

User.signup = function(userData, callback){

        // Validate data
        // Save data - User
        // Create role mapping
        // return token
}

User.remoteMethod(
    'signup', 
    {
      accepts: [{ arg: 'userData', type: 'object' }],
      returns: { arg: 'token', type: 'object' },
      http: { verb: 'post' }
    });
```

But, signup doesn't show up in the explorer. Could you please help?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually an [open issue](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/397) regarding how to handle this situation better. Right now it isn't pretty, but you can do it. The easiest way given your situation is probably going to be to create a simple boot script to extend `User`.

In `server/boot/` create a new file: `a-new-user.js` (Unfortunately, the file **must come alphabetically before `explorer.js`** otherwise the new remote method won't show up in the explorer interface.) Simply add the code below in that file and restart your application:

```
module.exports = function (app) {
    var User = app.models.User;

    User.signup = function(userData, callback){
        // ...
        callback(null, 'some response data');
    };

    User.remoteMethod(
        'signup',
        {
            accepts: [{ arg: 'userData', type: 'object' }],
            returns: { arg: 'token', type: 'object' },
            http: { verb: 'post' }
        }
    );
};
```